# how to sync data between company's internal database and externally hosted application's database

Tags: asp.net, hosting, database-replication

My organisation (a small non-profit) currently has an internal production .NET system with SQL Server database. The customers (all local to our area) submit requests manually that our office staff then input into the system.

We are now gearing up towards online public access, so that the customers will be able to see the status of their existing requests online, and in future also be able to create new requests online. A new asp.net application will be developed for the same.

We are trying to decide whether to host this application on-site on our servers(with direct access to the existing database) or use an external hosting service provider. 
Hosting externally would mean keeping a copy of Requests database on the hosting provider's server. What would be the recommended way to then keep the requests data synced real-time between the hosted database and our existing production database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to sync back and forth between two in-use databases will be a constant headache. The question that I would have to ask you is if you have the means to host the application on-site, why wouldn't you go that route?

If you have a good reason not to host on site but you do have some web infrastructure available to you, you may want to consider creating a web service which provides access to your database via a set of well-defined methods. Or, on the flip side, you could make the database hosted remotely with your website your production database and use a webservice to access it from your office system.

In either case, providing access to a single database will be much easier than trying to keep two different ones constantly and flawlessly in sync.

Comment: Thanks @LeviBotelho for your response. Our management feels that we may not have the necessary resources(manpower/hardware) to reliably host it ourselves. But, being the sole developer for our organisation, I was wondering if I should talk them into keeping it on-site for sake of application simplicity. The load will then fall upon our network engineers on whether they can provide the upkeep needed to host the application ourselves.  Having a web service hosted here would also mean a 100% up-time expectation on our servers.

Comment: I think @LeviBotelho has a valid point. Is there any reason to not allow both sites (internal and public-facing) to consume the data hosted remotely?

Comment: If your management doesn't think that you can maintain the site yourself, I would still argue for the webservice solution (either way around). While you do need 100% uptime, the actual work required is far less for a service than a whole site. You are going to spend far more time hunting down sync errors than keeping your WS up and running, that is for sure. And after all, doesn't any business-critical software (including your current software) need more or less 100% uptime? I think the service alternative is a good compromise which will require the least work in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If a webservice is not practical (or you have concerns about availability) you may want to consider a queuing system for synchronization. Any change to the db (local or hosted) is also added to a messaging queue. Each side monitors the queue for changes that need to be made and then apply the changes. This would account for one of the databases not being available at any given time.

That being said, I agree with @LeviBotelho, syncing two db's is a nightmare and should probably be avoided if you can. If you must, you can also look into SQL Server replication.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the data is the same, customer submitted data. Currently it is being entered by them through you, ultimately it will be entered directly by them, I see no need in having two different databases with the same data. The replication errors alone when they will pop-up (and they will), will be a headache for your team for nothing.